# Perl formatting a string

Tags: perl, format, string-formatting

I'm trying to format a string which has three columns. The first column data length can be different so I don’t know how to format my string in a right way.

```
for my $k(keys %results) {
   my ($k1,$k2);
   # $k1 and $k2 are always equal to '-' or '+'
   # $k = "nnn_12_555_addd";
   ...
   format STDOUT =
@<<<<<<<<<< @> @>
$k, $k1, $k2
.
   write;
}
```

How do I make the first column `@<<<<` to keep the right size?

If the `$k` value is longer than the specified `<`'s, I'm losing a part from that value in the output...

#### Sample input

```
$k1 = '+'
$k2 = '-'

$k = 'aaa_bbb'
output:
aaa_bbb            +    -

$k = 'aaa_bbb_ccc'
output:
aaa_bbb_ccc        +    -

$k = 'aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd'
output:
aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd    +    -
```

Comment: Can you add sample input and expected output?

Comment: @choroba added some samples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you forget about Perl's [format()](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc#format) and use [printf()](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc#printf-FILEHANDLE-FORMAT%2C-LIST) instead:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $k1 = '+';
my $k2 = '-';

for my $k (qw/ aaa_bbb  aaa_bbb_ccc  aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd /) {
    printf "%-20s%-5s%-5s\n", $k, $k1, $k2;
}
```

#### Output

```
aaa_bbb             +    -
aaa_bbb_ccc         +    -
aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd     +    -
```

---

#### Update

If you want to fit the first column width to the longest of the values, you can use a dynamic field width in *printf*. A format specifier like `%*s` takes two values from the parameter list: an integer width for the fields and a string.

The program would look like this:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use List::Util 'max';

my $k1 = '+';
my $k2 = '-';

my @k_vals = qw/ aaa_bbb  aaa_bbb_ccc  aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd  aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd_eee /;
my $w = max map length, @k_vals;

for my $k ( @k_vals ) {
    printf "%-*s %-5s%-5s\n", $w, $k, $k1, $k2;
}
```

#### Output

```
aaa_bbb             +    -
aaa_bbb_ccc         +    -
aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd     +    -
aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd_eee +    -
```

Comment: and what can i do if `$k` is longer than 20 characters?

Comment: @user3544092: What do you want to happen?

Comment: @choroba keep the string formatted? i mean the spaces between first columnt to second must be determinated according to the longest value of column 1 and it must be used for all other lines to keep the final output the same

Comment: Does anyone still use `format` in anger? I have used it for the sake of some training, but ... never since.

Comment: @Sobrique: It's quite awkward laying out big reports using `printf`, so `format` has its uses there. I tend to use [Perl6::Form](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl6::Form) in similar situations to where a *here document* would be more appropriate. It's a huge improvement over the Perl 5 version